# Retired, want to buy a mobile home; how to finance?

Tags: 403b

I have 125,000 in a 403b and just retired. I plan on relocating to Florida and want to purchase a mobile home that costs 45,000. How can I finance the purchase? A mortgage with my credit union with payments coming from my 403b? Or just take a lump sum out of my 403b?

Comment: Will you be approved for that mortgage? What are the terms?

Answer (score 3):

Do you think your 403b will earn more than the mortgage interest rate?  If so, then mortgage seems the way to go. Conservative investment strategies might not earn much more than a 3-4% mortgage, and if you're paying 5-6% it's more likely you'll be earning less than the mortgage.

From another point of view, though, I would probably take a loan anyway just from a security standpoint - you have more risk if you put a third of your retirement savings into one purchase directly, whereas if you do a 10-15 year loan, you'll have more of a cushion.  Also, if you don't outlive the mortgage, you'll have had use of more of your retirement income than otherwise - though I do wonder if it puts you at some risk if you have significant medical bills (which might require you to liquidate your 403b but wouldn't require you to sell your house, so paying it off has some upside).

Also, as @chili555 notes in comments, you should consider the taxation of your 403(b) income.  If you pull it out in one lump sum, some of it may be taxed at a higher rate than if you pulled it out more slowly over time, which will easily overwhelm any interest rate differences.  This assumes it's not a Roth 403(b) account; if it is Roth then it doesn't matter.

Comment: What about the tax consequences of withdrawing $45,000 from the 403b?

Comment: @chili555 Hmm.  I guess I didn't really think $45k was likely to move the tax needle much (as it's small enough that, at least for me, in retirement I don't think it would end up in a higher marginal rate).  But it's a good thing to consider - you might want to mention that in an answer.

Comment: It's not the marginal rate; it's the tax itself. If I have to pay say 6% in tax for a withdrawal from my 403b, then a 4% (possibly deductible) mortgage instead is by far the better deal, no?

Comment: But you will always pay tax on the withdrawal. Only diff is do you pay it all now or over time, maybe you have lower marginal rate over time.

Comment: @chili555 - how can someone have a marginal 6% federal tax bracket? 10/15/25, not 6.

Comment: As I said, it's not the marginal rate, it's the tax itself. However, any of the rates you quote is well in excess of commonly available mortgage rates.

Comment: @chili555 But you will always pay tax on withdrawals.  Withdraw $45k now, pay tax on it.  Withdraw $5k per year for 10 years, pay tax on it.  If the entire amount is at the same rate, then it doesn't make a difference which route you go, tax wise.  If the 45k pushes you into a new tax bracket, though, some of it is taxed at a higher rate; then, sure, it would have a negative implication.  But it all depends on the tax situation of the OP, which we have no details of, so it's just speculation (hence my note in the answer).

Comment: And don't forget that paying the mortgage off means a larger total amount of withdrawals, meaning more tax ultimately paid - so even if the 45k has a bit in the next bracket up, taking out 50k might mean paying more tax overall.

Comment: IF the tax brackets are the same 10-20 years from now and IF your own income, deductions and tax bracket are the same. In short, why pay 6% or 10% or 15% to use your own money when you can rent someone else's money for 3%; i.e. a mortgage.

Comment: Moreover, by keeping the cash, most of us can earn more than the 3% in investment returns over the life of the mortgage.

Comment: You're still going to pay 10 or 15% ... and otherwise I think my answer agrees with your statements generally (read the first paragraph), though with caveats.